# Android maximum media player instances clarification

Tags: android

In my app we have to play multiple sounds at the same time.We are using media player to do this currently, the issue we have is in android 2.1 we cannot create more than 7 media player instances.But in higher versions (>3.0) it works fine.Can somebody guide me on how to proceed this problem without using sound pool.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by using ogg files instead of using mp3 files in my application,ogg files consumes less amount of memory.